# How to change Pivot to ScrollViewer with VisualStateManager in UWP?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-10, uwp

Currently I have a ScrollViewer that contains three grids next to each other horizontally (left, middle, right). But when the screen is narrow I want it to change into a Pivot with those three same objects. So I managed to make a Pivot and that works fine, but now I want to build a VisualStateManager around it to automatically change between the ScrollViewer and the Pivot when the width of the screen changes. Is this possible? If not, do you know how I can manage to do this with some other feature of UWP?

The three items are just simple grids that contain listviews, so don't worry about those. However I can show the Pivot object:

```
<Pivot>
   <Pivot.Items>
      <PivotItem Header="Left grid">
         <Grid x:Name="LeftGrid" />
      </PivotItem>

      <PivotItem Header="Middle grid">
         <Grid x:Name="MiddleGrid" />
      </PivotItem>

      <PivotItem Header="Right grid">
         <Grid x:Name="RightGrid" />
      </PivotItem>
   </Pivot.Items>
</Pivot>
```

And this is the ScrollViewer object:

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="scrollViewer">
   <Grid>
      <Grid x:Name="detailsGrid">
         <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
         </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
         <Grid x:Name="LeftGrid" />
         <Grid x:Name="MiddleGrid" />
         <Grid x:Name="RightGrid" />
      </Grid>
   </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

And this is the VisualStateManager:

```
<VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
   <VisualStateGroup>
      <VisualState x:Name="WideState">
         <VisualState.StateTriggers>
            <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="400" />
         </VisualState.StateTriggers>
         <VisualState.Setters>
            <Setter Target="?" Value="?" /><!-- which values to I set here? -->
         </VisualState.Setters>
      </VisualState>
      <VisualState x:Name="NarrowState">
         <VisualState.StateTriggers>
            <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="400" />
         </VisualState.StateTriggers>
         <VisualState.Setters>
            <Setter Target="?" Value="?" /><!-- which values to I set here? -->
         </VisualState.Setters>
      </VisualState>
   </VisualStateGroup>
</VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
```

Currently there is one root-Grid that contains the VisualStateManager and below the VSM, within the root-Grid are the Pivot and ScrollViewer. How should I continue?

Comment: I would research the [RelativePanel](http://visuallylocated.com/post/2015/04/09/In-depth-with-the-Windows-RelativePanel.aspx). It's a new control in Windows 10 XAML that can achieve what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to add or remove the control within `VisualStateManager`.

Alternately, you can place the `Grid` and the `Pivot` in the same page and set one of these `Visibility` to `Collasped` by default. And all in VisualStateManager is just setting the `Visibility` property of the `Grid` & `Pivot`.

Comment: This is what I was looking for. However now I'm using the same code twice, is there a way to store a grid in some variable and use a reference to that variable? I'm still a XAML newbie.

Comment: Try `UserControl` that allows you to encapsulate your XAML or code-behind in one control and use it in other XAML.